# .Net : Creating dynamic JSON via deserialization

Tags: json, .net, json.net

I need to generate a JSON of below structure

```
"data": {
    "id": "1",
    "week04282020": "0",
    "week05052020": "624,746",
    "week05122020": "0",
    "week05192020": "0",
    "week05262020": "0",
    "may-20": "624,746",
    "week06022020": "0",
    "week06092020": "0",
    "week06162020": "0",
    "week06232020": "0",
    "week06302020": "0",
    "jun-20": "0",
    "quarter22020": "624,746"
.....
}
```

The week etc have the format `weekMMDDYYYY` and so on. These dates are changing as expected. So, alternatives for me are to use an `ExpandoObject` in a class like below -

```
class MyData
{
    public dynamic ExpandoObject Data = new ExpandoObject();
}

var data = MyData();
data.Data.id = 1;
data.Data.week04282020 = 0;
data.Data.week05052020 = 624746;
...

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Is there a better way to achieve this without using dynamic/ExpandoObject? Please note that I might have to port this code to Java later on, which does not supports dynamic or ExpandoObject equivalent.

Any other way (not string concatenation/manipulation) to generate this JSON without using a class serialization would also be fine.

Thanks

Comment: `Dictionary<string, string>` if order doesn't matter

Comment: [`SortedDictionary<string, string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2) if order _does_ matter

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dictionary<string, string>` for your `Data` property, like this:

```
class MyData
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RWW0Bk

Note that Java has a `HashMap<K,V>` class which is roughly equivalent to `Dictionary<K,V>`.